# compare fromdate to todate validation in jQuery

Tags: jquery, date

When comparing two dates like fromDate to toDate duration between two dates

for ex:

(mm/dd/yy; 12/15/2013 to 01/15/2014)

we can use validate in below way.  When comparing in jQuery please follow the below steps and you will get succeed.

```
var fromDate=(formObj.dateFrom).replace(/\D/g,'/');
var toDate=(formObj.dateTo).replace(/\D/g,'/');
var ordFromDate, ordToDate;ordFromDate= new Date(fromDate); ordToDate= new Date(toDate);

if(ordToDate<ordFromDate){$("#divIdtodisplayErrMesg").append('<span class="red">Please select valid order date range.</span>');
return false;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
          $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
        }
    });
    $("#txtToDate").datepicker({ 
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
           $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
        }
    });  
});
```